# Rewriting old and new urls to same page with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Have a page currently with the URL /results-details.php?mls_number=stringofnumbers.

I want it to re-write to: /results-details/stringofnumbers

However I want that to basically resolve back to the original page.

I'm also changing all the URLs on the site internally to point to the URL. So I have two re-write rules:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mls_number=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule (.*) /new-homes/results-details/%1? [R=301,C]
RewriteRule ^results-details/([0-9]+)$ results-details.php?mls_number=$1
```

The second rule works fine on it's own with internal links in the /results-details/stringofnumbers form, but the first one doesn't chain properly to the second one and not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Basically trying to retain any links to the old URLs that might be out there but start using the new URS internally.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

YOu need to match against the actual request and not the URI, because the rewrite engine loops:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /new-homes/results-details\.php?mls_number=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^ /new-homes/results-details/%1? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^results-details/([0-9]+)$ results-details.php?mls_number=$1
```

Comment: Tried this and it doesn't seem to do anything. Not sure if it's failing to match or failing to re-write the URL or just looping.